# MSBuild sets TargetFrameworkDirectories incorrectly

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.5

When I try to build a C# Console Application (and possibly others) it appears that `TargetFrameworkDirectories` is set incorrectly; in particular it omits the Facades directory.

Since I've been trying to diagnose the problem for a while, here is a list of possibly relevant facts.

- The problem manifested itself when trying to build in Visual Studio 2012 a project that referenced the Reactive Extension libraries (managed using NuGet).  The error (or warning) was `warning MSB3267: The primary reference "System.Runtime", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"`.  The problem occurs during msbuild executing `ResolveAssemblyReference`
- I can reproduce the error from command line with msbuild, which seems simpler
- Other workstations do not exhibit the problem.  Running msbuild with verbosity turned up on a good machine and on the bad machine turned up some differences in the log file
- On a good machine `TargetFrameworkDirectories` (a parameter of `ResolveAssemblyReference`) is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\` but on a bad machine it lacks the second entry (the Facades directory)
- Scanning through the good and bad msbuild log files the following differences turn up:

  1. Target `AssignProjectConfiguration` is skipped in the bad build, but runs in the good build
  2. A number of targets like `GetInstalledSDKLocations` are skipped in the good build but are not mentioned in the bad build
  3. The `ResolveAssemblyReference` task is passed `Assemblies` with `Implicit=true` in the good build but not in the bad build.
  4. The `ResolveAssemblyReference` task is passed the task parameter `TargetFrameworkDirectories` with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\` in the bad build, but the good build the Facades directory (see above) as a second item.

Since this is driven by `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets` I diffed that file on the good and bad machine.  They contained many differences.  The first difference is the project element (line 17) which has an extra attribute `TreatAsLocalProperty="OutDir"` on the good machine.  On the good machine the targets file contains more comments, such as `<!-- VS10 without SP1 and without VS11 will not have VisualStudioVersion set, so do that here -->`. Jumping to the `AssignProjectConfiguration` target, the good machine has `Condition="'$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' != '' or '@(ProjectReference)'!=''"` while the bad machine has `Condition="'@(ProjectReference)'!=''"` (which I assume explains why it was skipped).

One final thing I tried was repairing "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5" and "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack".  It did not help.

Any advice would be appreciated, especially if I can avoid reinstalling Visual Studio 2012!

UPDATE: It seems that reinstalling .NET 4.5 followed by "merely" repairing VS2012 solved my problems.  My best guess as to what caused this problem is that somehow my Microsoft.Common.targets was altered to an old version.  I have no idea what could have altered the targets file.

Comment: This seems like a .NET issue. Perhaps just reinstall/repair .NET 4.5?

Comment: Should have added that I repaired .NET 4.5.  I'll modify the post to point this out.

Comment: After asking [a related question on the MSBuild forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/e9d339fb-31cf-47d7-86c7-2bdfb77027a6) it seems that _reinstalling_ .NET (as opposed to just repairing) fixed the issue. @leppie if you make your comment into an post I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: You can post your own answer and mark it as the solution (rep for you!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @leppie it was a .NET problem.  For some reason repairing .NET did not seem to fix the problem.  However reinstalling .NET 4.5 (followed by repairing VS2012) did seem to fix it.